# Advice with Bash script to perform actions on certain conditions

Tags: linux

I have written part of a small (hopefully) simple script that checks a URL for an error being returned using wget. It then outputs the error to a log file for alerting purposes. What I then want to do is for a service to be restarted automatically.

I will be running this check via a cronjob every minute, so if there is still an error after the service has been restarted already, I don't want the script to restart the service again.

Is there a elegant way to achieve this?

This is what I have so far, a wget check, if error code 5, output to the health.log file and restart nginx, however, I don't want this looping around restarting nginx every 60 seconds when running on a cronjob.

```
#!bin/bash

URL='http://some-url-here/'
LOG='/var/log/nginx/health.log'

wget -q $URL
if [ $? = 5 ] ; then
echo "$(date). SSL Error." > $LOG
sudo service nginx restart
exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- it's ok if we create a new file (`restart.log`), otherwise we could append a new line to `$LOG`
- we'll only perform a `restart` attempt every 10 minutes (aka 600 seconds)
- OP wants to append to the current `$LOG` (current code overwrites/replaces the entire file each time the script runs)

Proposed method:

- use a new file to store the epoch time at which the last `restart` was attempted
- before trying a `restart` we compare the current epoch with the saved epoch and only proceed (with the `restart`) if the difference in epochs is greater than 600 seconds

Modifying OP's current script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                        # add "/" at start of shebang path

URL='http://some-url-here/'
LOG='/var/log/nginx/health.log'

RLOG='/var/log/nginx/restart.log'
touch "$RLOG"

wget -q $URL

if [ $? = 5 ] ; then
    echo "$(date). SSL Error." >> "$LOG"           # replace ">" with ">>" so that we append to $LOG

    read -r prev_epoch < <(tail -1 "$RLOG")        # retrieve epoch of last restart attempt
    prev_epoch="${prev_epoch:-0}"                  # default to 0 if there is nothing in the file

    printf -v curr_epoch '%(%s)T'                  # use printf builtin to grab current epoch and save in variable 'curr_epoch'
    # curr_epoch=$((date '+%s'))                   # uncomment if 'printf -v' is not available in your system

    delta=$((curr_epoch - prev_epoch))

    if [[ "${delta}" -gt 600 ]] ; then
        sudo service nginx restart
        echo "${curr_epoch}" > "$RLOG"             # replace ">" with ">>" if you want to maintain a history of restart epochs; the "tail -1" should insure we only grab the 'last' entry
        exit
    else
        echo "it has only been ${delta} seconds since last restart attempt; skipping restart" >> "$LOG"
    fi
fi
```